# How to create a dynamic memoize function with multiple users in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I have a function that calculates bounds:

```
function Canvas() {
  this.resize = (e) => {
    this.width = e.width;
    this.height = e.height;
  }

  this.responsiveBounds = (f) => {
    let cached;

    return () => {
      if (!cached) {
         cached = f(this);
      }
      return cached;
    };
  }
}
```

and I have a function that uses this `Canvas` object bounds:

```
function Box(canvas) {
  let fBounds = canvas.responsiveBounds(({ width, height }) => {
    return {
      width,
      height
    };
  });

  this.render = () => {
    let bounds = fBounds();

    console.log(bounds);
  };
}
```

Now when canvas `resize` function is called, bounds will change, and I need to reflect this change (by clearing the cached variable somehow). I can't make `cached` global because `responsiveBounds` is called by multiple users.

Comment: but you can make it a property of `Canvas` instead of the local variable (which isn't going to work anyways).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two different options:

### 1. Register listeners to the change

```
function Canvas() {
    let listeners = [];

    this.resize = (e) => {
        this.width = e.width;
        this.height = e.height;
        listeners.forEach(listener => listener());
    };

    this.responsiveBounds = (f) => {
        let cached;

        listeners.push(() => cached = undefined);

        return () => {
            if (!cached) {
                cached = f(this);
            }
            return cached;
        };
    }
}
```

Here each `responsiveBounds` execution context has its own listener registered, so it can take care of clearing its private cache.

### 2. Collect all caches in a Weak Map

With a (Weak) Map you can create a store for private cache variables, keyed by the function object for which they are relevant:

```
function Canvas() {
    let cached = new WeakMap;

    this.resize = (e) => {
        this.width = e.width;
        this.height = e.height;
        cached.clear();
    };

    this.responsiveBounds = (f) => {
        return () => {
            let result = cached.get(f);
            if (result === undefined) {
                cached.set(f, result = f(this));
            }
            return result;
        };
    }
}
```

The nice thing about Weak Maps is that if the function returned by `responsiveBounds` gets garbage collected, and also the corresponding `f`, then the corresponding `WeakMap` entry can be garbage collected as well.

The advantage of the first solution is that the `resize` method does not need to know anything about what the listeners are doing (whether they are dealing with a cache or entirely something else).